# Is there a way to create GitHub repositories with PowerApps using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, automation, yaml, github-actions, powerapps

Is there a way where we can automate the process using GitHub Actions to create a GitHub Repository based on a PowerApps Form filled by a user?